# Join related data when Serialize Json and geojson

Tags: python, json, django, serialization, geojson

In Django Views:

I want join the data from two table. `lease_geom.query` gives right query but when i serialize the `lease_geom` there is no data from related table.

```
def mapdata_leases_geom(request, lic):

    # only one table data
    lease_geom = Ssm_El_Ml_Pl_Blocks.objects.filter(license=lic).select_related()
    q = lease_geom.query
    lease_geom = serialize('geojson', lease_geom,
          geometry_field='geom')
```

> The function just return the geojson of 1st table.

Answer (score 0):

After working of so many days i found the solution there you may create your own **SERIALIZER** by using SERIALIZERs classes in django.
I am posting solution that works for me.

## CUSTOMIZED GEOJSON SERIALIZER

```
from django.utils.encoding import force_text
from django.contrib.gis.serializers.geojson import Serializer as geoSerializer

class geoJsonSerialiser(geoSerializer):

    # ADDING FIELDS TO GEOJSON
    def add_field(self, current, obj):
        current['grant date'] = force_text(obj.lease.grant_date)
        current['expiry date'] = force_text(obj.lease.expiry_date)
        return current

    # OVERRIDING GET_DUMP_OBJECT METHOD IN GEOJSON SERIALIZER

    def get_dump_object(self, obj):
        current = self.add_field(self._current, obj)
        data = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": current,
        }
        if ((self.selected_fields is None or 'pk' in self.selected_fields) and
                    'pk' not in data["properties"]):
            data["properties"]["pk"] = obj._meta.pk.value_to_string(obj)
        if self._geometry:
            if self._geometry.srid != self.srid:
                # If needed, transform the geometry in the srid of the global geojson srid
                if not HAS_GDAL:
                    raise SerializationError(
                        'Unable to convert geometry to SRID %s when GDAL is not installed.' % self.srid
                    )
                if self._geometry.srid not in self._cts:
                    srs = SpatialReference(self.srid)
                    self._cts[self._geometry.srid] = CoordTransform(self._geometry.srs, srs)
                self._geometry.transform(self._cts[self._geometry.srid])
            data["geometry"] = eval(self._geometry.geojson)
        else:
            data["geometry"] = None
        return data
```

**May be useful for others**